# Graphic layer to Json format : ArcGIS api for javascript

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

In my application I am converting annotation feature to graphic layer and then converting same graphics to json for printing. I know how to converted annotation features to graphic but I do not have knowledge how to convert graphic to json.

Answer (score 0):

The Graphic class has a [toJson()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/graphic-amd.html#tojson) method - would that work?

Comment: Thanks GavinR, can u provide some link of toJson() function examples that will be really helpful.